# Rust Closures concept

Tags: rust, closures, mutable, ownership

I am unable to understand this concept here about Rust closures. As in my code count is default `i32`. When I create mutable closure then it will take mutable reference of variable used in it as mentioned in documentation.

When I call inc closure in loop and try to print value of count inside loop I will get mutable borrow used error but if I print value of count outside of the loop it’s fine. Even in loop when I call `inc()` closure before print macro `inc()` goes out of scope then why it provoke error.

```
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;

    let mut inc = || {
        count += 2;
    };

    for _index in 1..5 {
        inc();
        println!("{}", count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create the closure, it borrows mutably the `count` variable. It is forbidden to access the `count` variable through another reference while the mutable borrow is alive (including the `count` variable itself). The closure is dropped when it is no longer used, at which point it releases the borrow which makes it possible to access `count` again.

```
fn main() {
    let mut count = 0;

    let mut inc = || {
        count +=2;
    };
    // Now we can't access `count`

    for _index in 1..5 {
        inc();
        // println!("{}", count);
        // Here we can't access `count` because it is borrowed mutably by `inc`
    }
    // Here `inc` is dropped so `count` becomes accessible again
    println!("{}", count);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Jmb,I got it. after declaration as mutable we can't access variable used in closure in between the declaration and call of closure.

just one more clarification what is lifetime of closure? is it static by default ?

Comment: No, it is not static. The lifetime ends when it can no longer be used (no more code path leads to a statement where it is used). In this case the `inc` in the `for` loop is the last use, so after the for loop ends the lifetime ends, too, and it is dropped.